# How do I configure multiple guests in a virtual network

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, multiple-computers

I am using VMWare Workstation 7 and I have 2 guest OS's installed, Windows Server 2003 configured as an Active Directory Domain Controller with RAS (NAT), DNS and DHCP installed.

The first guest has 2 NIC's installed. The first is a virtual NIC (VMNet1) configured as Host-only with a subnet address of 192.168.0.0 and subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and has a fixed IP address of 192.168.0.1. The second NIC is bridged to the physical NIC in the host and has a fixed IP address of 192.168.1.1. RAS is installed to provide NAT across the 2 subnets and is working great.

The second guest OS (XP Pro) has a single virtual NIC and is obtaining it's IP address, gateway and DNS details from the DHCP server running on the W2K3 guest. The NIC in the XPvm is configured using the same Host-only VMNet1 as NIC1 in the W2K3vm.

I can ping from the XPvm to the W2K3vm, but cannot ping from the W2K3vm to the XPvm? What am I doing wrong, why can I ping one way but not the other?

Comment: I know this seems fairly obvious, but is the firewall turned off on the XP machine?

Comment: Blatantly obvious, but easily overlooked . . .Thanks Hyppy :O)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your firewall off on XP :-)

Comment: Rather than turn it off completely set up a rule that allows both incoming and outgoing connections to local IP addresses.

Comment: As XP runs as host-only why not turn it of completly.